# Best practice for storing emails encrypted in a database when working with Zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, encryption

I'm using Zend Framework with a LAMP stack. The client has requested protection of sensitive data, email included. In this project, emails will be used in two ways: for sending automated messages and for sending newsletters.

Has anyone worked with this? What algorithms are fast, reliable and can be used with a variable encryption key? Where should I store the encryption key? What engine should the database table use?

Comment: simply storing in the db should be sufficient, its not publicly available. Encrypting them in the db probably wont actully add anything, if the db is stolen then they had access to the file system where the encryption key was stored.

Comment: You can use PHP's cryptological features, or the cryptological features (if any) of your database to store encrypted data.  However, if we're talking emails, then there's a big problem.  Unless the person you're sending the email to has a public key then you can't send them encrypted email anyway.  As soon as it hits the wire it has to be plaintext.

Comment: @Dagon It's not uncommon for attackers to gain access to data without gaining access to the file system (SQL injection), so I think the idea has some merit.

Comment: there's not no merit, just so little, that I would be sure that it would be better to spend time else where.

Comment: Do you need to read only e-mails sent to a specific user or should people be able to see all kind of different mails? If just user-specific you could ask the user to enter a key which is part of the encryption. That way you won't be able easily to retrieve the content because you need user known info. The issue is that if they lose that key they won't be able to recover the data anyway. So that's a quite big risk in some situations.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming, that by `email` you mean email address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, these are my 2cent.

For data that needs to be both encrypted and decrypted on the fly, I would suggest symmetric key algorithms, and the first that comes to mind is [Blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29). It is both fast, and relatively safe.

As to the variable keys. Usually there is little to no merit in having a different key for each entry that needs to be both encrypted and decrypted. Thus, I'd recommend using a single key, that is set in config file somewhere.

If you do need to have a key for each of the users/records, I'd recommend not keeping them in the db. Save them to flat-files on the disk.

As to table engine, it should not matter which one you choose, as long as it's not memory based.

---

As to merit - I think there is merit, if the client specifically asks for it. Even if there is technically little reason to create this encryption, this will contribute to the clients feeling of safety. Sure, it could be a false one, but it does help keep the data a bit more safe, and lets the client sleep more soundly. Therefore, if **the client asks for it**, go for it!

Comment: you cant of worked with many real clients, if you think pandering to every request no matte the merit is a good idea.

Comment: I'd push back a little on this "if the client asks for it, do it" statement.  As professionals, it's important to also educate the client.  Sure, if the client wants it after knowing the cost/value/performance, then go ahead.  On a topic of encryption and "sensitive data", guess who the client is going to try and place liability on when the data is stolen and decrypted?  Being up front on the security and liability and have it in writing is a good idea.  And don't guarantee the security.

Comment: @Dagon please lets skip the offensive parts, ok? No need for them. As to jmbertucci, I agree. I never said to guarantee safety, but thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to do this, the answer Janis Peisenieks gives is a good starting point.

As far as I know, there's no safe way of storing keys in PHP - this means that an attacker who gets a moderate level of control over your system can retrieve the key from a config file, and use that to decrypt the data.

An attacker who wanted to know the email addresses of your users would have several options to retrieve that data - as GordonM writes, if your system sends email to those users, that email is relatively easily to intercept, and whilst the body may be encrypted, to "to address" is not.

Just checking that you will be hashing (not encrypting) passwords (if your system uses these?)